# Nginx not serving precompiled assets in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have a RoR3 server deployed in Amazon EC-2.

My assets are precompiled. I ran rake:assets:precompile as a part of my capistrano deployment task.

For example:

`assets/home/separator.png` is precompiled in `public/assets/home/separator-7abf67950e9a27f371d2b5638de4320b.png`

I cant see the separator.png  in the file
`public/assets/home/manifest.yml`, why?

This is my nginx configuration for the assets:

```
location ~* ^/(assets)/ {
        expires 1y;
       add_header Cache-Control public;

       # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
       # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
       # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
   }
```

The Rails app is searching for `assets/home/separator-f4571b5883207774be6edc5745de4755.png`, which doesnt exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted the Rails app?

Comment: Yes. I think that I have a problem configuring nginx.

Comment: It sounds more like a Rails problem if the asset is not listed in the manifest. What happens if you `curl -I http://{your host}/assets/home/separator-7abf67950e9a27f371d2b5638de4320b.png`?

Comment: It works well if I do that.

Comment: So the file is there and nginx can serve it correctly. I think something went wrong during your precompilation or deployment, or the Rails app is somehow seeing an old manifest, like you're running an old copy of the application in memory on top of a new set of files. I would say redeploy the application and watch for any error messages during precompilation or restarting the app.

Comment: For some reason the generated html is not looking for the right file. It is not looking for the file indicated in manifest.yml

Comment: If I download http://<myserver>/assets/manifest.yml I see the right file there. I mean, separator-f4571b5883207774be6edc5745de4755.png is not there!